# discord.py guild.members only returns 4 members instead of all members

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am trying to create a discord selfbot that can print all of the members names in the console when >>>Members is typed. It should then delete the >>>Members message and print the names in the console. I am aware this is against TOS.

Here is my code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents().all()
bot = commands.Bot(">>>", self_bot=True, intents=intents)

@bot.command()
async def Members(ctx):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    members = ctx.guild.members
    for member in members:
        print(member.name)

bot.run("shit I leaked my token", bot=False)
```

It manages to delete the message but then it only prints four members names to the console. I have no idea what is going wrong here. My intents seem to be configured correctly. What am I doing wrong here? The members returned seem to be random per server. They could be bots, online, or offline people. The closest problem I have seen online is guild.members only returning the author of the message (This can be fixed with intent). Help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much.

Comment: you could try manually fetching it with `members = await guild.fetch_members(limit=150).flatten()`

Answer (score 0):

As of October 27, 2020, Discord updated their gateway by adding intents. The part that is most likely affecting your code, as seen in [this](https://support-dev.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/360056426994) post, is quoted here:

### For bots that do not have the GUILD_MEMBERS intent --------

> If you do not need to do anything when a guild member joins, leaves, or is updated, you do NOT need the members intent. You cannot get a full member list to fill the cache, but in the majority of cases, a full member list is not necessary for building a persistent cache.

You will need to enable the **Server Members Intent** in your Developer Portal in order to have the entire cached list of members your bot can see.

*Note: If your bot is in less than 100 guilds, you are perfectly fine to enable this privileged intent, but once you go over 100 guilds, you will need to get your bot verified (it will have a visual verified checkmark next to the bot tag) and get data whitelisting, link [here](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/360040720412).*

### Alternatively

You could iterate through the guild members using `fetch_members`:

```py
async for member in ctx.guild.fetch_members(limit=1000):
    print(member.name)
```